# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==301 , heroku error

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku

I have tried to remove that file pywin32 from requirements but still it shows this error. I have searched for a method to remove this module but till now I have not found anything useful.

This is my requirements.txt file

```
asgiref==3.3.4
astroid==2.7.3
backcall==0.2.0
bcolors==1.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
chardet==4.0.0
cheroot==8.5.2
cloudpickle==1.6.0
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==3.4.7
decorator==5.0.9
defusedxml==0.7.1
distlib==0.3.2
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.4
django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
django-extensions==3.1.3
django-filter==2.4.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
ipykernel==5.5.5
ipython==7.24.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==5.9.3
jaraco.functools==3.3.0
jedi==0.18.0
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-core==4.7.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
Markdown==3.3.4
matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==8.8.0
oauthlib==3.1.1
parso==0.8.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.2.0
platformdirs==2.3.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.19
psycopg2==2.9.1
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.9.0
PyJWT==2.1.0
pylint==2.10.2
pymongo==3.11.4
pypiwin32==223;platform_system == "Windows"
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.1
pywin32==301;platform_system == "Windows"
pyzmq==22.1.0
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
simplejson==3.17.2
six==1.16.0
social-auth-app-django==5.0.0
social-auth-core==4.1.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
spyder-kernels==2.0.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
termcolor==1.1.0
toml==0.10.2
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.0.5
urllib3==1.26.5
virtualenv==20.4.7
wcwidth==0.2.5
web.py==0.62
whitenoise==5.3.0
wrapt==1.12.
```

I am getting this error when I use git push heroku master

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==301 (from -r /tmp/build_53cc9ad9/requirements.txt (line 57)) (from versions: none)
remote:  ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==301 (from -r /tmp/build_53cc9ad9/requirements.txt (line 57))
```

This is the full error message

```
 Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: eea743c20e6fc3b759e5d6061939723626cbb910
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version eea743c20e6fc3b759e5d6061939723626cbb910
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to urlshortenerfreecodecamp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/urlshortenerfreecodecamp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/urlshortenerfreecodecamp.git'
```

Comment: try to clear the cache in heroku..because it use a temporary requireements file..use heroku repo:purge_cache -a <APPNAME>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove it before committing, perhaps you are still pushing the old requirements.txt file.
or use
pip uninstall pywin32==301 and regenerate the requirements.txt file by using pip freeze>requirements.txt